# ReactJS redirection with id in link

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to redirect to another page from a button click. I have created my button on-click function as follows.

```
const buttonOnClick = (id) => {
     this.props.history.push('/teams/team' + id);
}
```

The idea is that when I render the button, I add the buttonOnClick function with the id I want the link to have. Each button will have a different id based on how I'm creating it. This is my button code:

```
<button onClick={ buttonOnClick(id) }>Go</button>
```

However, this executes the function right as the button is rendered (without being clicked) because I'm using (), which is expected. How do I pass the id to the function without it executing the function on rendering?

Thanks.

Comment: If you need to define a function that has properties to pass in, wrap it with an arrow function instead of calling it: `<button onClick={() => buttonOnClick(id) }>Go</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are calling that function instead of passing the function to onClick, change that line to this:

```
<button onClick={ () => buttonOnClick(id) }>Go</button>
```

=> called Arrow Function, which was introduced in ES6, and will be supported on React 0.13.3 or upper.